# How to ignore a file in two diff directories in .gitignore

Tags: git

My directory structure looks like this:
[directory stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zouxo.png)

How would I ignore the two config.js from my git repo in .gitignore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore only the two specific ones then add

```
backend/config.js
frontend/config.js
```

If you want to ignore all config files in subdirectories, as well as the directory that `.gitignore` is placed, add

```
**/config.js
```

In case you were tracking the mentioned files before and you would like to stop tracking them from now on, you can run `git rm --cached <file name>`

Comment: I'm not sure why but in VSCode the config files aren't light like the other ignored folders and files, does that mean it's not working?

Comment: Have you been tracking them before? If so, they will keep being tracked, even if you update your `.gitignore`

Comment: Yes, it was being tracked before, how do I make it untracked now?

Comment: `git rm --cached <file name>`, that won't delete it from your machine, it will just stop tracking it.

If you want to delete it as well, `git rm <file name>`.